# Resolving $x^6-x^4-1=0$ (only interested in $x\simeq1.21$)

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm struggling to find the solution to $x^6-x^4-1=0$, so far I tried changing variable ($u=x^2$) to work around $u^3-u^2-1=0$ instead but I'm still having a hard time.

And again, I'm only interested in finding the exact expression of the value $x\simeq1.21$.

Also I'm sorry if I posted to the wrong site (there was this one or MathOverflow).

Comment: Since the equation is effectively a cubic, there is an exact form...but it certainly isn't pretty.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E6-x%5E4-1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly it won't let me check on the maths behind it.

Comment: You probably need to look up Cardano's solution of the cubic, which is no doubt what WA is using.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) is a discussion of the closed form for a cubic.  It is straight forward, but quite messy.  In practice, numerical methods tend to be preferred (though of course it depends on what you are looking for).

Comment: Are you asking for a derivation of Cardano's formula which is the formula that gives you the real root of the cubic?

Comment: By the time you're done with all the substitution you might just lose focus for a few minutes. Especially with the existing complexity of the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMMENT.- Pay attention to Lulú's comment above. Numerical methods give faster and sufficiently approximate results for you. Here I show you is a sample (maybe interesting for you) of how the root you want determines all the other five roots.

Since $a$ is root if and only if $-a$ is root, the polynomial  $x ^ 6-x ^ 4-1$ is divisible by $x ^ 2-a ^ 2$ and then you have
$$x^6-x^4-1=(x^2-a^2)(x^4+(a^2-1)x^2+a^2(a^2-1))$$
Then $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-a^2\pm\sqrt{-3a^4+2a^2+1}}{2}}$$ gives four solutions and $x=\pm\sqrt{a^2}$ are the other two ones.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to derive the exact solution for $x$. Let $u=\frac1{x^2}$. Then, the equation becomes

$$u^3+u-1=0\tag 1$$

Compare with the identity

$$4\sinh^3a+3\sinh a -\sinh 3a =0$$

and recognize that

$$\sinh a =  \frac{\sqrt3}2u,\>\>\>\>\>\sinh 3a = \frac{3\sqrt3}2$$

satisfy (1). Then, $a = \frac13\sinh^{-1}\frac{3\sqrt3}2$ and the solution for $u$ is

$$u = \frac2{\sqrt3}\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)$$

Thus, the solution for $x$ is

$$x = \frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{\sqrt2}\left[ \sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)\right]^{-\frac12}=1.21$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x^2$ to face
$$t^3-t^2-1=0$$
Solving the cubic for $t$, there is only one real root. Using the hyperbolic method, you have
$$t=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{29}{2}\right)\right)\right)\approx 1.4655712$$